# How to resize an image with relative positioned child images?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a tournament diagram.
This is the blank diagram.
[image: The blank diagram]

What I am trying to do is to insert the logos from the different teams into the blue spots. What I did is to create a div which contains the diagram and then insert the logos with a relative position to the picture.

```html
<html>
<style>
    .head{
        position: relative;
        left: 10px;
        bottom: 90px;
    }
</style>
<body>
<div>
    <img src="diagram.png">
    <img src="logo.png" class="head">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The first logo would then appear in the first spot.

When I resize the diagram with the screen I don't know how to resize the logos in the same way so they stay at the same spot and have the right ratio. Because I would like to fit the diagram on every screen I want to resize the whole thing so it fits on each screen. I don't care about mobile.
Is there a way to resize the whole thing at once?

Comment: Dont use fixed pixel values, use %. Sort of like https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/dgcha

Answer (score 0):

Provide us with more codes and the clear problem you have. and if you have any other questions feel free to ask in the comment.

What you are doing right now is hard coding every logo to its position that's why when you resize the browser window it doesn't fit as you wanted.

I suggest you read flex-box documentation and here's a good tutorial:

> https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this method is that you're trying to make the images relatively positioned to the body, meaning if one were to resize the body (or the viewport I should say), the images would become offset from the background tournament diagram. If you want them to stay in place no matter the size of the viewport, there are two option I see:

1. Create a tournament diagram in pure CSS and place every image into the corresponding div.
2. Use a 2D design program to create an image with all of the logos already on the tournament diagram.

Here's an example of method 1 using CSS Flexbox.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.team-logo {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
.downwards-stem {
  width: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  background: teal;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="team-logo">Insert Logo</div>
  <div class="downwards-stem"></div>
  <div style="display: flex; margin-top: -20px;">
    <div class="team-logo">Insert Logo</div>
    <div class="team-logo">Insert Logo</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Here's an example using a 2D Design program. I prefer to use [Figma](https://www.figma.com/)
[image: A tournament stack with logos placeholders]